# Do Until inside automate Power Automate never end

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow

I have this Do Until, where I am checking if a variable named i = Frequency. but the do until never ends:

[image]

Although the Frequency is a SharePoint number field.

Any advice?

Comment: Is your Initialize Variable 'i' set to a Type of Integer?

Comment: Make sure you are using the Number/Integer type for variable "i" and also initializing it with 0 value. Also, I think there is some issue with Do Until action at Microsoft end and Microsoft team is working on fixing it.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP yes the i is an interger .. what type of issue , do you know?

Comment: I have seen few other users reporting similar issue about do until loop never ending.